# Handlebar doesn't render a collection field correctly

Tags: collections, meteor, render, handlebars.js

I'm having problem trying to use a collection field named `created` in a template. Is that a reserved word, or something?

The part of the template that's struggling looks like this:

```html
{{#each threads}}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="forumShowThread?id={{_id}}">{{topic}}</a></td>
        <td>{{creator.username}}</td>
        <!-- The line below is the evil one. -->
        <td>{{created}}</td>
        <td>{{lastPost.poster.username}} {{datetime lastPost.posted}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

The threads I find in my console in my browser are the following:

```
[
Object
_id: "ngEtonq8XM36KtG3S"
created: 1375881336372
creator: function (){
creatorId: "ZmKpMdhP4GtzQo98e"
lastPost: function (){
posts: function (){
subCategory: function (){
subCategoryId: "axgd2xzctkfmphmwM"
topic: "Testing"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
_id: "XafEMvAvcRzpBKxG3"
created: 1375882602652
creator: function (){
creatorId: "ZmKpMdhP4GtzQo98e"
lastPost: function (){
posts: function (){
subCategory: function (){
subCategoryId: "axgd2xzctkfmphmwM"
topic: "Testnign again"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
_id: "CZmf5MfqZrB28SLPB"
created: 1375883440242
creator: function (){
creatorId: "ZmKpMdhP4GtzQo98e"
lastPost: function (){
posts: function (){
subCategory: function (){
subCategoryId: "axgd2xzctkfmphmwM"
topic: "And another shoot"
__proto__: Object
]
```

Obviously three threads, and they all have a created field. But the browser shows the following:

```html
<tr>
    <td><a href="forumShowThread?id=CZmf5MfqZrB28SLPB">And another shoot</a></td>
    <td>Peppe L-G</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Peppe L-G 7 August 2013 15:50</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><a href="forumShowThread?id=XafEMvAvcRzpBKxG3">Testnign again</a></td>
    <td>Peppe L-G</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Peppe L-G 7 August 2013 15:36</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><a href="forumShowThread?id=ngEtonq8XM36KtG3S">Testing</a></td>
    <td>Peppe L-G</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Peppe L-G 7 August 2013 15:35</td>
</tr>
```

Why isn't the `created` field showed?

I tried to use `<td>{{this.created}}</td>` instead of `<td>{{created}}</td>`, and then the browser shows the following:

```html
<tr>
    <td><a href="forumShowThread?id=CZmf5MfqZrB28SLPB">And another shoot</a></td>
    <td>Peppe L-G</td>
    <td>1375883440242</td>
    <td>Peppe L-G 7 August 2013 15:50</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><a href="forumShowThread?id=XafEMvAvcRzpBKxG3">Testnign again</a></td>
    <td>Peppe L-G</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Peppe L-G 7 August 2013 15:36</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><a href="forumShowThread?id=ngEtonq8XM36KtG3S">Testing</a></td>
    <td>Peppe L-G</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Peppe L-G 7 August 2013 15:35</td>
</tr>
```

The `created` field now works for the first thread, but not the rest. What's going on?!

In case it's relevant, here's the entire template:

```html
<template name="pageForumSubCategory">
    <div class="layoutContentForumSubCategory">
        {{#with subCategory}}
            <h1>
                <a href="forum">Forum</a>
                →
                {{name}}
                {{#if currentUser}}
                    →
                    <a href="forumCreateNewThread?id={{_id}}">New thread</a>
                {{/if}}
            </h1>
            {{#if threads.count}}
                <table border="2">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Topic</th>
                            <th>Creator</th>
                            <th>Created</th>
                            <th>Last post</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {{#each threads}}
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="forumShowThread?id={{_id}}">{{topic}}</a></td>
                                <td>{{creator.username}}</td>
                                <!-- The line below is the eveil one. -->
                                <td>{{this.created}}</td>
                                <td>{{lastPost.poster.username}} {{datetime lastPost.posted}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {{/each}}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            {{else}}
                <p>Well, it's more or less empty here (so far).</p>
            {{/if}}
        {{else}}
            <h1>
                <a href="forum">Forum</a>
                →
                ???
            </h1>
            <p>Hmm... There is no subforum with the given id. Strange, but there's nothing I can do about it. Sorry.</p>
        {{/with}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All templates already have a [created](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_created) property, which is callback (run when your template is created). The easiest solution is just to call the field something else like `createdAt` instead.

Comment: Hmm... Isn't the context switched when I'm using `#each`, so the documents `created` shadows the templates `created`? Or, obviously not (I tested, you're right). But now I see why the collection `Meteor.users` has a field called `createdAt`, which I've found a little bit odd ^^